# Javascript image.onload on multiple image only working for the last image

Tags: javascript, image, callback, onload

hello I have problem with something.onload. I wanna show 3 images, whenever it's already loaded. First I'll put the container of every image with opacity = 0 and whenever it's already loaded i'll change the number to 1.

```
// HTML
<div class="img-container" data-src="imgurl1">
</div>
<div class="img-container" data-src="imgurl2">

</div>
<div class="img-container" data-src="imgurl3">

</div>


// CSS
.img-container{
 opacity:0;
 width:100%;
}
.loaded {
 opacity:1;
}

// JS
window.onload = function(){
   var container= document.querySelectorAll('img-container');
   for(var i=0;i<container.length;i++){
      var temp = container[i];
      var img = Image();
      img.src = temp.dataset.src;
      img.onload = function(){
         temp.classList.add('loaded');  
      };
      temp.appendChild(img);
   }
}
```

When i run that code, only the last image is shown. When i inspect for every image, only the last image that have opacity = 1 (class loaded successfully added) and the other still have 0 opacity.

Am I missing some JS concept?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#forEach` as `for-loop` does not create scope for variables hence variables will get over-written after iteration and as `onload` is asynchronous, only last image will get affected.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var container = document.querySelectorAll('img-container');
  [].forEach.call(container, function(temp) {
    var img = Image();
    img.src = temp.dataset.src;
    img.onload = function() {
      temp.classList.add('loaded');
    };
    temp.appendChild(img);
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, almost forget that forEach will execute on every item independently. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of closures.

**Here is what is happening in your case:** 
Your for loop will execute synchronously and onload event will be handled by javascript using the event queue.

So technically, your for loop completes execution and then any event in the event  queue is executed.Therefore it only runs for i = last iteration

To overcome this you need to make your function an IIFE as and return a function that executes what is required:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var container= document.querySelectorAll('img-container');
   for(var i=0;i<container.length;i++){
      img.onload = (function(){
         return function(){
             var temp = container[i];
             var img = Image();
             img.src = temp.dataset.src;
             temp.classList.add('loaded');
             temp.appendChild(img);
         }  
      })(i);

   }
}
```

Comment: _"for loop completes execution and then event loop starts"_, I disagree....

Comment: @Rayon: I rephrased my explanation. All i meant was that events are added to the event queue and the execution stack is made only after javascript finishes its syncronous execution

Comment: @RahulArora Hmm i think there is some thing wrong with your solution. How come execute "img.onload" before defining the variable ?

Comment: @BaharudinAfif: If you can elaborate?